# Not Equal to in Inner Join

Tags: join, sql-server-2012, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have 3 scenarios to implement.

```
Case 1- When IM.Code=IME.Code and IM.Effective_st_dt=IME.effective_st_dt and IM.Effective_end_dt =IME.Effective-end_date
```

Action-
In this case i need to update the IM with currentMrp and currentCp.

```
Case 2- When IM.Code=IME.Code and IM.Effective_st_dt!=IME.effective_st_dt and IM.Effective_end_dt =IME.Effective-end_date
```

Action-
1.)Pick the recent Effective_st_dt record from IM and Update the Effective_end_date with (IME.Effective_st_dt)-1

2.)then Insert a new record from IME which has new effective_st_dt also this record lastMRP and lastcp is the currentmrp and Currentcp of the previous record which is updated in 1

Case 3- When IM.Code=IME.Code and IM.Effective_st_dt!=IME.effective_st_dt and IM.Effective_end_dt !=IME.Effective-end_date

Action-
1.)Pick the recent Effective_st_dt record from IM and Update the Effective_end_date with (IME.Effective_st_dt)-1

2.)then Insert a new record from IME which has new effective_st_dt also this record lastMRP and lastcp is the currentmrp and Currentcp of the previous record which is updated in 1

This is the script of my tables

```
Create Table IM 
(
    ID int idenetity (1,1)
    ,Code varchar(100)
    ,CurrentMrp float
    ,CurrentCP float
    ,lastMrp float
    ,lastCp float
    , effective_st_dt date
    ,effective_end_dt date
)

Create table IME
(
    Code varchar(100)
    ,CurrentMrp float
    ,CurrentCP float
    ,Effective_st_dt date
    ,Effective_end_dt date
)

insert into IM (code, currentMrp, currentCp, lastMRP, lastCP, effective_st_dt, effective_end_dt)
   Select 
      'CA123', 10.12, 5.0, 8.20, 4, '2014-05-01', '2014-05-31'
   union
Select 'CA123',15.0,5.0,10.12,8.20,'2014-06-01','2014-08-31'
union
Select 'CA121',50.0,15.0,45.0,25.0,'2014-04-01','2014-05-31'
union
Select 'CA121',75.0,25.0,50.0,15.0,'2014-06-01','2014-06-30'
union
Select 'CA131',53.0,12.0,35.0,10.0,'2014-05-01','2014-05-31'
union
Select 'CA131',60.0,15.0,53.0,12.0,'2014-06-01','2014-08-31'


Insert into IME (code,effective_st_dt,effective_end_dt)
Select ('CA123',20.0,5.0,'2014-06-01','2014-08-31')
union
Select ('CA123',25.0,6.0,'2014-06-20','2014-08-31')
union
Select ('CA123',35.0,7.0,'2014-07-15','2015-03-31')
```

please help me to solve this

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better you use left join instead of inner join in this particular case, else not equal to will not give you the correct results.